# Count how long pan Gesture is being held

Tags: uipangesturerecognizer

I am pretty new to iOS and first question here, sorry if you find it not full technical vocab yet

Anyways is it possible to calculate how long pan gesture is being held?
and then use that number in a for loop to implement a count?

For example user holding screen for 5 sec and my for loop would be i <= pangesturehold , i++

cheers

Answer (score 0):

For the view being touched you could implement the methods `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` and `- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`, and read the current time in both methods. The difference gives you the time the view was touched.
To get the current time, you can use `[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];`